# How to pass multiple values to a parameter in a GET API in angular 9+ using http client

Tags: javascript, angular, api, angular-httpclient, angular10

I'm getting an array of Id's like below:-

```
id=[1,2,3,4]
```

How to dynamically pass those  value from array id  to a parameter of a API request like this in angular:-

```
this.http.get(`/api/request?num=1,2,3,4`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the params like this:

```js
const num = [1,2,3,4]
this.http.get(`/api/request`, {params: {num}});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const ids: string = id.join(',')
this.http.get(`/api/request?num=${ids}`);
```

Or

```
const ids: string = id.join(',')
const options = { params: new HttpParams().set('num', ids) };
this.http.get('/api/request', options);
```

[Angular Doc](https://angular.io/guide/http#configuring-http-url-parameters)